# How do I convert a InputStream to BufferedImage in Java/Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, inputstream, bufferedimage

Yes, I'm that stupid. I'm trying to stick some groovy code together from various cookbook recipes, and I can't get from an InputStream to BufferedImage in Java/Groovy. Google is not being my friend at present.

Comment: I see your Google-foo is lacking Dycey-san. You must practice and make your sensei proud!

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
BufferedImage imBuff = ImageIO.read(object.getInputStream());
```

Should work...

Comment: as I already had a stream variable, it was as simple as `BufferedImage imBuff = ImageIO.read(myInputStrVar);`. Yes, I am stupid!

Comment: @Dycey No,you are not but he(Gans) is smart.

Comment: note: do not close the stream, InputStream will not be null but imagebuffer will be a null.  close it after the conversion.